# how do I install android-multi-bluetooth-library on android studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm a new beginner in Android Studio.2.3  I've downloaded android multi bluetooth library and copied and pasted it into project's subProject folder.  I need help to go from there.  Things like do I modify build.gradle (Project) or (Module.app).  I don't understand what to write in the dependencies.
Tried compile project(':subProject:AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary')
Tried Build Clean but errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: gradle maven repository is dead https://github.com/arissa34/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library/issues/10

**A. 1st Method (Edited: Try 2nd method)**

In app/build.gradle

Add this line 'com.ramimartin.multibluetooth:AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary:1.2-SNAPSHOT' inside dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.ramimartin.multibluetooth:AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary:1.2-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Now,in build.gradle (it is located in root of your project folder)

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://sfdn.ddns.net/maven2/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**B.  2nd Method**

https://github.com/arissa34/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library/blob/master/Bluetooth/Bluetooth_lib/target/AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

1. Copy the jar file to libs folder

[image: Android lib dir]

2. Right Click and click Add as library

[image: Android add as lib]

3. Click ok

[image: ok add lib]

***Note***:  If your app crash while running the app you may also need to include following in build.gradle

```
dependencies {

compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.0'

}
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends BluetoothActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public int myNbrClientMax() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBluetoothDeviceFound(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClientConnectionSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClientConnectionFail() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onServeurConnectionSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onServeurConnectionFail() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBluetoothStartDiscovery() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBluetoothCommunicator(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBluetoothNotAviable() {

    }
}
```

Comment: I copied the dependencies in build.gradle and did a build clean and received this: Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.ramimartin.multibluetooth:AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary:1.2-SNAPSHOT

Comment: More info:  the library I downloaded and unzipped is located in the project folder.  I no longer have it in the subProject folder.  Project folder:  SnowPlow/AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary along with the other files.

Comment: @rlakin you do not need to download library if you add above to  your build.gradle (Note that there are two different  build.gradle file ).You need internet connection and it will auto download dependencies for your app when you sync your project.

Comment: @rlakin you wanted this library https://github.com/arissa34/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library ,yes? also try 
    "compile 'com.ramimartin.multibluetooth:AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary:1.1-SNAPSHOT'"

Comment: @M M, I tried 1.1 and 1.2  Both failed sync; Takes over a hour to Gradle sync.  I have two build.gradle, one is project and the other is app:  Project is where I put the url under repositories and the library compile in app.    
      allprojects {
    repositories {
       
        maven {
            url "http://sfdn.ddns.net/maven2/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }

}        In the app:                       dependencies {
    compile 'com.ramimartin.multibluetooth:AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary:1.1-SNAPSHOT'
  
}

Comment: @rlakin delete line added in both build.gradle and try above updated answer.gradle maven repository is dead. Try above answer It is working for me.

Comment: @M M Copied library .jar into project.  Ran build clean, OK.  I got a big task ahead of me.  My existing project has two RN42s with a PIC at each end.  Each side is linked with their UART.  One is the control receiver and the other end is the control transmitter.  They connect with Bluetooth.  My smart phone has an app to act as a control transmitter if and when the RN42 control transmitter is disconnected, because all three cannot connect at the same time is why I'm interested in the AndroidMultiBluetoothLibrary.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @rlakin if the answer worked then you can accept the answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers